# Django: Login Session not Persisting on Page Load

Tags: python, django, mongodb, session, persistence

Libraries I am using:

1. django-nonrel/django@nonrel-1.5
2. pymongo>=2.8
3. django-nonrel/djangotoolbox
4. django-nonrel/mongodb-engine
5. python-jsonrpc
6. django-ckeditor==4.5.1

Hey there. I have stepped through my code, looked at many different places, but I just can't seem to figure out what would be stopping my Django session from persisting on my local install.

I've narrowed it down to three possibilities I think may be happening:

1) I am missing something on the back-end that needs to be run/installed before the sessions will persist
2) The time on my session is not long enough? Though, when I check the session it clearly states that it will expire in half a month. So I do not think this is high possibility.

If I do not redirect after logging in, the login page shows my session as active. It is only when I navigate to another page, that I am immediately logged out. That being said, it may be logging me out earlier, without my knowledge. But the logout route is not being hit, so yes I've covered my bases and ensured that wasn't the problem.

Let me know if you have any suggestions on what I can check next, to help solve this problem! And thank you!

EDIT: Extra info while I check to see if I may post the settings.py file (lots of info in there, but some is private)

http://imgur.com/jyiiN7O&sQE75HN&f3cEXsq  Images of a GET and POST, and then the failed attempt at loading another page due to lack of log in session..

And here is the route I tried to hit AFTER log in. (To be clear, the log in works perfectly fine. The DB is updated, the session is stored, the page reloads with the UI changed  to appear to be logged in. Only on another page load does it disappear.)

```
def play(request):
    if not request.user.is_authenticated():
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('login'))

    try:
        n = ReleaseNote.objects.order_by('-date')[0]

    except:
        n = None

    return render(request, 'help/play.html', {'note': n})
```

Comment: What is the symptom of being "logged out"? How are you verifying that this is happening?

Comment: The UI of the navbar changes to a logged in state, with the ability to access account information and other details. :)

Comment: Right. And this only happens when you go to another page? So, have you verified that you're actually passing the user's logged-in status to that template?

Comment: It is saved within the request. I traced the redirect and the value is saved up until the new page is loaded. That being said, with the default authenticate and login functions that come with Django, would this be automatic, or does it specifically save to a location I need to pass?

Comment: What do you mean "saved within the request"? Obviously, a redirect is a new request. How are you persisting the status?

Comment: Request object, plus database store (using the standard session module from Django)

Comment: Could we see a bit of code?

Comment: For sure, but you'll need to let me know which code! I am certain this is either 1) settings.py problem  OR 2) an issue with passing the session along to the next page.

Let me know which code you'd like to see.

Comment: Post your settings and the view that's having issues please. If possible also post the template you're using on that view.

Comment: Checking with the boss on that one, before I upload the information. But here is a sample of stuff (check my edit).

Comment: https://dpaste.de/LSNM  Some of the session-specific settings.

Comment: I can't understand what you think the screenshot of request/response values is showing. There's no indication of anything being set on /login that is subsequently lost.

Comment: And are you saying that in the /play view the code gets past the `request.user.is_authenticated` guard, but then fails to display the logged-in block in the template? If so you'll definitely need to post that part of the template itself.

Comment: Actually, it fails to get past that guard. So I guess the variable is not getting passed. But it does indeed get set. So that makes me think something is ... removing it? From scope. I can't think of a valid reason why this would occur, though.

Comment: Got it. Needed to edit my hosts file to add in the site name (added the line: localhost site.test.address.here)

Answer (score 0):

What if you try it this way, works like a charm :

```
class Login(View):
    template_name = ['your_app_name/login.html', 'your_app_name/home.html']

def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    form = UsersForm()
    return render(request, self.template_name[0],{"form":form,})


def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    username = request.POST['username']
    password = request.POST['password']
    user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
    if user is not None:
        login(request, user)
        #if login is succesfull it takes you to home page:
        return render_to_response(self.template_name[1],RequestContext(request))
    else:
        #if is not, takes you to login page again
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('cost_control_app:login'))
```